# How do I redirect a not found FLV file to a 404 FLV file, using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, mod-rewrite

Using .htaccess, how do I permanently redirect all not found *.flv files in one directory to a 404.flv file in the same directory. For example:

If this file is not found:
**example.com/flv/*.flv**

Use this file:
**example.com/flv/404.flv**

Here's what I have so far (I'm very bad):

```
RewriteCond /flv/(.*).flv !-f
RewriteRule ^ /flv/404.flv [L,R=301]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two separate conditions. And you want to return a 404 response.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/flv/.*\.flv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/flv/404.flv [L,R=404]
```

Comment: Hi,
For some reason I'm getting an Internal Server error. Do I need to modify anything in here besides the file name and the directory?

Comment: Here's what I get
 /home/example/public_html/.htaccess: RewriteRule: invalid HTTP response code for flag 'R'

Comment: I guess you're not running httpd 2.2 then. In that case you'll have to point `ErrorDocument 404` to a script and handle it in there.

Comment: I'm using Apache 2.0.63. 
Can you give me a quick example, to make sure I'm doing it right?
Thanks a bunch

Comment: Use something like `ErrorDocument 404 404.php`, and then in the script check the value of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to see if it redirected from a missing .flv file, then use `header()` to set the response MIME type, and `readfile()` to stream the file to the client.

Comment: I've upgraded to Apache 2.2. Your solution worked fantastic! Thank you!